# ARIMA() error TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start'

Tags: time-series, typeerror, arima

I used this code:
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_model import ARIMA

model = ARIMA(ts_log, order=(2, 1, 0))

This error came out:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in 
    model = ARIMA(ts_log, order=(2, 1, 0))

File "C:\Users\April\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 996, in **new**
    mod.**init**(endog, order, exog, dates, freq, missing)

File "C:\Users\April\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 1015, in **init**
    super(ARIMA, self).**init**(endog, (p, q), exog, dates, freq, missing)

File "C:\Users\April\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\arima_model.py", line 435, in **init**
    super(ARMA, self).**init**(endog, exog, dates, freq, missing=missing)

File "C:\Users\April\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py", line 58, in **init**
    self._init_dates(dates, freq)

File "C:\Users\April\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tsa\base\tsa_model.py", line 191, in _init_dates
    start=index[0], end=index[-1], freq=freq)

TypeError: **new**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start'

I really appreciate your help! :)

Answer (score 3):

It worked when upgraded to new version statsmodels (1.12.0). Initial version is (0.9.0)

```
pip install --user statsmodels -U
```