# arma_generate_sample cannot return the correct value for modeling, so I would like to add sm.tsa.ARIMA

Tags: python, python-3.x, statsmodels, arima

All the other online information was off the mark, such as lying or having a different version.
I would appreciate it if you could answer how to solve it.
I just want to model an AR process such as ''yt = 0.33yt-1 + et.''

```
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import arma_generate_sample

def make_arma(nobs=250):
  # arma(1,1) => xt = ρxt-1 + et - θet-1
    arparams = np.array([0.444, 0.333])
    maparams = np.array([0])
    arparams = np.r_[1, -arparams]
    maparam = np.r_[1, maparams]
    np.random.seed(2014)
    
    y = arma_generate_sample(arparams, maparams, nobs)
### If you do not enter the code below this, it seems that all are 0.
    model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(y, (1,0), trend='n').fit(disp=0)
    data = model.params
 
    return data

data = make_arma(nobs=250)
data[-30:]
```

```
TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'trend'
```

statsmodel==0.12.2
https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/releases
This is a bugfix release from the 0.12.x branch. Users are encouraged to upgrade.

Notable changes include a fix for a bug that could lead to incorrect results in predictions using the new ARIMA model (when d> 0 and trend ='t'), and a bug in the autocorrelation LM test. It will be.

[ARIMA() error TypeError: __new__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'start'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61512385/arima-error-typeerror-new-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-start)

Answer (score 0):

The second argument to `ARIMA` is not the order, it is `exog`. So you need to set the order which is easiest if you use a keyword. Also, order is a 3-element tuple of the form `(p,d,q)`, so you need `(1,0,0)`. Finally, `disp` is not part of fit. Finally, you need set `maparams` to have a `1` in the first position (typo in the original post where `maparam` was being updated, not `maparams`.

```py
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
from statsmodels.tsa.arima_process import arma_generate_sample

def make_arma(nobs=250):
    # Simulate a basic AR model
    # arma(1,1) => xt = ρxt-1 + et - θet-1
    arparams = np.array([0.444, 0.333])
    maparams = np.array([0])
    arparams = np.r_[1, -arparams]
    maparams = np.r_[1, maparams]
    np.random.seed(2014)
    
    y = arma_generate_sample(arparams, maparams, nobs)
    ### If you do not enter the code below this
    ### it seems that all are 0.
    model = sm.tsa.ARIMA(y, order=(1,0,0), trend='n').fit()
    data = model.params
 
    return data

data = make_arma(nobs=250)
data[-30:]
```